# Equality and inequality with infinitesimal number

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, epsilon-delta

Is the following statement true?

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.
If $0\leq a-b < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, then $a=b$.

What if I replace '$<\epsilon$' by '$\leq \epsilon$' and make the following statement?

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.
If $0\leq a-b \leq \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, then $a=b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Proposition**
>
> Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers that for every $\varepsilon>0$ satisfy $0\leq a-b<\varepsilon.$ Then $a = b$.

**Proof.** Assume for contradiction that $a\neq b$. By the original inequality we have that 
$$b\leq a < b+\varepsilon. $$

Since $a\neq b$ and $b\leq a$ we have that $b<a$. This means there exists a strictly positive number $\delta>0$ such that $b+\delta = a$, and hence $a = b+\delta < b + \varepsilon$, which implies that $0<\delta < \varepsilon.$ The inequality holds for any $\varepsilon>0$ so choose $\varepsilon = \delta/2>0$ from which the inequality is $0<\delta <\delta/2$ which is a contradiction.

We conclude that $a = b$. $_\square$

The proof can easily be adjusted to the second claim.

Answer (score 4):

The following two statements are equivalent:

1. "$0 \leq a-b < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$" implies "$a = b$"
2. "$0 \leq a-b \leq \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$" implies "$a = b$"

Indeed, suppose the first.
Then to prove the second, suppose $0 \leq a-b \leq \delta$ for every $\delta$. Fix arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$.
Let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$; so $0 \leq a-b \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$.
So by the first property, $a=b$.

The converse is trivial.

Comment: Thanks. I see. Then, is statement 1 true?

Comment: @norio Both statements are true

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How so? Is it the definition of equality? Or, is it something one can prove?

Comment: If for every $\varepsilon>0$ it holds that $0\leq a-b < \varepsilon$, then $0\leq a-b \leq \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \varepsilon = 0$, and hence $0 \leq a-b \leq 0 \iff a = b.$

Comment: O.K. I got it. To show that statement 1 is true, suppose (i) that ''$0\leq a-b < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$", but (ii) that "$a\not=b$". Then, it must follow that $0<a-b$, which imlies $0<(a-b)/2 < a-b$. However, by setting $\epsilon = (a-b)/2$, it follows from assumption (i) that $a-b < (a-b)/2$. Here we see a contradiction. Therefore, assumption (i) implies $a=b$.

Comment: @Eff Thanks. In your way, I feel a bit uncertain about if I can introduce $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0+} \epsilon$ in place of 'any $\epsilon$'. I am scared if there is any number between $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0+} \epsilon$ and the smallest $\epsilon$ that I can think of.