# If $a\leq b \leq c$, and $c-a$ can be made arbitrarily small does that mean $a=b=c$? What is the actual thing that justifies this inference?

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation

The question is pretty clear I think but for context, I'm reading chapter 13 of Spivak's Calculus, entitled "Integrals" and came across a seemingly simple step in a proof which left me wondering about why it was justified.

A function $f$ that is bounded on an interval $[a,b]$ is defined as integrable on that interval if

$$\sup\{L(f,P)\}=\inf\{U(f,P)\}\tag{1}$$

where $P$ denotes any partition of $[a,b]$, $L(f,P)$ denotes the lower sum of $f$ for partition $P$, and $U(f,P)$ denotes the upper sum of $f$ for partition $P$.

The number represented by $(1)$ is the integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$, and is denoted $\int_a^b f$.

There is also a theorem that in essence restates the definition

> Theorem 2: if $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ then, $f$ is integrable on
> $[a,b]$ if and only if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a partition
> $p$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$

At some point, Spivak presents the following theorem

> Theorem 5: If $f$ and $g$ are integrable on $[a,b]$, then $f+g$ is
> integrable on $[a,b]$ and
>
> $$\int_a^b (f+g)=\int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$$

**I have a question about a seemingly very simple step at the end of the proof.**

Here is the proof of the first part, that $f+g$ is integrable.

> Since $f$ and $g$ are integrable, there are partitions $P'$ and $P''$
> such that
>
> $$U(f,P')-L(f,P')<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
> $$U(g,P'')-L(g,P'')<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
>
> Let $Q$ be the partition containing $P'$ and $P''$. Then from a lemma
> presented in the text, we can infer that
>
> $$U(f,Q) \leq U(f,P')$$ $$L(f,Q) \geq L(f,P')$$
>
> and
>
> $$U(g,Q) \leq U(g,P'')$$ $$L(g,Q) \geq L(g,P'')$$
>
> Hence,
>
> $$U(f,Q)+U(g,Q)\leq U(f,P')+U(g,P'')$$ $$L(f,Q)+L(g,Q) \geq
>  L(f,P')+L(g,P'')$$
>
> $$U(f,Q)+U(g,Q)-(L(f,Q)+L(g,Q)) \leq
>  U(f,P')+U(g,P'')-(L(f,P')+L(g,P''))<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$
>
> That is, $U(f+g,Q)-L(f+g,Q)<\epsilon$. So $f+g$ is integrable on
> $[a,b]$.

Here is the proof of the second part, that $\int_a^b (f+g)=\int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$.

> Let $P={t_0,...,t_n}$ be any partition of $[a,b]$.
>
> Let
>
> $$m_i=\inf\{ (f+g)(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$$ $$m_i'=\inf\{
>  (f)(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$$ $$m_i''=\inf\{ (g)(x): t_{i-1}
>  \leq x \leq t_i \}$$
>
> $$M_i=\sup\{ (f+g)(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$$ $$M_i'=\sup\{
>  (f)(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$$ $$M_i''=\sup\{ (g)(x): t_{i-1}
>  \leq x \leq t_i \}$$
>
> It can be shown that $m_i \geq m_i'+m_i''$ and $M_i\leq M_i'+M_i''$.
>
> Therefore,
>
> $$L(f,P)+L(g,P) \leq L(f+g,P)\tag{2}$$
>
> $$U(f+g,P) \leq U(f,P)+U(g,P)\tag{3}$$
>
> Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together we have
>
> $$L(f,P)+L(g,P) \leq L(f+g,P) \leq U(f+g,P) \leq U(f,P)+U(g,P)$$
>
> Now, by definition of the integral $\int_a^b f$ and $\int_a^b g$ we
> have
>
> $$L(f,P)\leq \int_a^b f \leq U(f,P)$$
>
> $$L(g,P)\leq \int_a^b g \leq U(g,P)$$
>
> Therefore,
>
> $$L(f+g,P)=L(f,P)+L(g,P)\leq \int_a^b f +\int_a^b g \leq U(f,P)
>  +U(g,P)=U(f+g,P)\tag{4}$$
>
> But since $f+g$ is integrable, then for (any) P we have
>
> $$L(f+g,P) \leq \int_a^b (f+g) \leq U(f+g,P)\tag{5}$$

At this point, intuition would tell us that $\int_a^b (f+g)=\int_a^b f +\int_a^b g$.

Here is how Spivak justifies this last step:

> Since $U(f,P)-L(f,P)$ and $U(g,P)-L(g,P)$ can both be made as small as
> desired, it follows that
>
> $$U(f,P)+U(g,P)-[L(f,P)+L(g,P)]$$
>
> can also be made as small as desired; it therefore follows from $(4)$
> and $(5)$ that
>
> $$\int_a^b (f+g)=\int_a^b f +\int_a^b g$$

I can sort of see intuitively that if $a\leq b \leq c$, and $c-a$ can be made arbitrarily small then that should mean that $a=b=c$. But what is the actual thing that justifies this inference?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820808/42969

Comment: $c-a= \epsilon$. $c -a = (c -b)+(b-a ) =\epsilon$ since each term is positive this would imply each term is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Your notation is muddled, you mention $P'$ and $P''$ but $P''$ doesn't appear in the equations after that.

Comment: @SuzuHirose You are right there were a few spots where I forgot to add an extra "$'$", ie I used $P'$ instead of $P''$. Should be fixed now.

Comment: All this $\epsilon, \delta $ symbolism is only meant to present the statement "zero is the least non-negative real number" in a formal and unambiguous fashion. The quoted statement holds true if "real" is replaced by "rational" and thus is nothing great or deep but just the way these particular ordered fields work.

Comment: Spivak's argument is about two fixed numbers, say, $a, b$ lying in variable interval $[c, d] $ ie $c\leq a\leq d, c\leq b\leq d$ and $c, d$ can be made as close to each other as we please. Then we have $0\leq |a-b|\leq d-c$ and finally by last comment $a=b$.

Comment: @EthanBolker I think you're right. I'm going to delete my comment.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking to this in the title and at the end (I haven't read the whole question)

> I can sort of see intuitively that if $≤≤$ , and $−$ can be made
> arbitrarily small then that should mean that $==$. But what is the
> actual thing that justifies this inference?

Ignore $b$ for the moment. If the difference between $a$ and $c$ is less than $\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$ then they must be equal. If not, take $\epsilon = (c-a)/2$ to reach a contradiction.

Since $b$ is between $a$ and $c$ and $a=c$, $b$ must be equal to $a$ as well.

Comment: Consider the following example. $S_1=a\left ( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right )^2$ and $S_2=a[1+\frac{1}{n}]$. Then $S_1<a<S_2$. By increasing $n$ we can get $S_1$ and $S_2$ as close to $a$ as we want, and thus we can make them as close to each other as we want. Yet, they are never equal to $a$. This is slightly different because we have $<$ instead of $\leq$. But isn't it actually the same thing?

Comment: I believe the example above shows that though we start with $a\leq b\leq c$ and $c-a$ can be made arbitrarily small, we have a counterexample to the conclusion that $a=b=c$. In the example above, we concluded that $a<b<c$.

Comment: But now that I think about it, the example is not a true counterexample. $S_1$ and $S_2$ are sequences of numbers. Any particular element of $S_1$ and any particular element of $S_2$ would need to be taken as $a$ and $c$, and they don't satisfy the assumption that $c-a$ can be made as small as possible. The claim is the opposite: we start with an $a$ and $c$ and claim that they satisfy the assumption. Then they must be equal.

Comment: But my example does elucidate another question that was in the proof in my question. If $S_1<a<S_2$ and $S_1<b<S_2$ for all $n$, then $a=b$. I think this is because there can only be one number $a$ satisfying $S_1<a<S_2$ for all $n$. If there were two, we'd have to account for the numbers in between them, which would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Your last comment is correct (although your definitions of $S_1$ and $S_2$ are confusing because they don't mention $n$). My answer addresses the actual question you asked. When you have "another question" you should post another question. And try to narrow questions down. We did not need the whole proof from Spivak.

Answer (score 1):

> if $a\leq b \leq c$, and $c-a$ can be made arbitrarily small then that should mean that $a=b=c$.

Precisely, this means

> if $a\leq b \leq c$, and $c-a<\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$, then $a=b=c$.

The trick is that, if $a\neq c$, then $a<c$. Consider $\varepsilon=\frac{c-a}{2}>0$. Then $c-a<\varepsilon \iff c-a<\frac{c-a}{2}$ which is absurd since $c-a>0$.

Therefore, $c=a$. Since $a\le b\le c$, anti-symmetry of the order relation implies that $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 0):

We start with the following statements

$$L(f+g,P)\leq \int_a^b f +\int_a^b g \leq U(f+g,P)\tag{4}$$

$$L(f+g,P) \leq \int_a^b (f+g) \leq U(f+g,P)\tag{5}$$

where $(4)$ and $(5)$ are true for any partition $P$.

and the fact that $f+g$ is integrable, which means that $\forall \epsilon>0$, we can find some partition $P$ such that

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon\tag{6}$$

This situation can be seen in a simplified manner by letting

$$U(f+g,P)=c$$
$$L(f+g,P)=a$$
$$\int_a^b (f+g)=b_1$$
$$\int_a^b f +\int_a^b g=b_2$$

Then we have
$$a \leq b_1\leq c\tag{1}$$
$$a \leq b_2\leq c\tag{2}$$

and $c-a$ can be made arbitrarily small.

Assume $b_1 \neq b_2$.

Case 1: $b_1<b_2$

Let $d \in (b_1,b_2)$.

Then if we choose $\epsilon=\frac{b_2-b_1}{2}$ we have

$$c-a<\frac{b_2-b_1}{2}$$

$$c<a+\frac{b_2-b_1}{2}<b_1+\frac{b_2-b_1}{2}=\frac{b_1+b_2}{2}<b_2$$

$$\bot$$

Case 2, $b_2<b_1$ is symmetric to case 1, and thus results in $\bot$ as well.

Thus, by contradiction, we conclude that $b_1=b_2$.

Finally note the following distinction.

If we are given $a$ and $c$ and we say that for these specific numbers it is true that $c-a<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$, then as shown by Taladris's answer, it must be the case that $a=c$. If there is some $b$ such that $a \leq b \leq c$ then $a=b=c$.

There is a slightly different setup: a given $b$ and variable $a$ and $c$ such that $a \leq b \leq c$ and it is always possible to choose $c$ and $a$ such that $c-a<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$. In this case, $a$ doesn't have to be equal to $c$.

For example, let $a(n)=b(1-\frac{1}{n})$ and $c(n)=b(1+\frac{1}{n})$.

We can make $a(n)$ and $c(n)$ as close to each other as we want but $a(n)<c(n)$ for all $n$.

What we can show for this second case, however, is what I showed above: that there can be at most one number between $a(n)$ and $c(n)$.