# Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 13 "Integrals", Proof of problem 10

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

The following is a problem from chapter 10 of Spivak's Calculus, entitled "Integrals"

> 10. Prove, using the notation of Theorem 5, that
>
> $$m_i'+m_i''=\inf\{f(x_1)+g(x_2):t_{i-1}\leq x_1, x_2\leq t_i\}\leq
>  m_i$$

I previously asked a question where I showed the [entire proof of Theorem 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4468403/if-a-leq-b-leq-c-and-c-a-can-be-made-arbitrarily-small-does-that-mean-a-b).

Here is the part that is relevant for problem 10 above

$$m_i=\inf\{ (f+g)(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$$ $$m_i'=\inf\{
 f(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$$ $$m_i''=\inf\{ g(x): t_{i-1}
 \leq x \leq t_i \}$$

The solution manual solution is

> The first inequality is a special case of Problem 8-13, and the second
> inequality follows from the fact that $\{f(x_1)+g(x_2):t_{i-1}\leq
>  x_1, x_2 \leq t_i\}$ contains all numbers in $\{f(x)+g(x):t_{i-1}\leq
>  x \leq t_i\}$, and possibly some smaller ones.

The cited problem 8-13 essentially shows the following result, in my own words

> If $A$ and $B$ are two nonempty sets of numbers which are bounded
> above, and $A+B$ is the set of all numbers $x+y$ with $x\in A$ and $y
> > \in B$, then $\sup{(A+B)}=\sup{A}+\sup{B}$.

The solution refers to the first inequality. Which inequality is it referring to? By "special case of 8-13", does Spivak perhaps mean an analogous result that $\inf{(A+B)}=\inf{A}+\sup{B}$?

If we take $A=\{f(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$ and $B=\{g(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$, then $$A+B=\{f(x)+g(y): f(x) \in A, g(y) \in B\}$$$$=\{ f(x)+g(y): t_{i-1}\leq x,y \leq t_i \}$$ and

$$\inf{A}+\inf{B}=\inf{(A+B)}$$

$$m_i'+m_i''=\inf\{ f(x)+g(y): t_{i-1}\leq x,y \leq t_i \}$$

**Regarding the second inequality, is the reasoning below correct?**

Assume $m_i<m_i'+m_i''$.

Then there exists some $x_1 \in [t_{i-1},t_i]$ such that for all $x$ and $y$ in $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ we have

$$m_i\leq f(x_1)+g(x_1)<m_i'+m_i''\leq f(x)+g(y)\tag{1}$$

Note that if this weren't the case, then $m_i'+m_i''$ would be a lower bound of $\{ (f+g)(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$, but this can't be since by assumption $m_i=\inf\{ (f+g)(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$.

But $(1)$ must be true also for $x=x_1$ and $y=x_1$ which leads to

$$f(x_1)+g(x_1)<f(x_1)+g(x_1)$$
$$\bot$$

Therefore, $m_i\geq m_i'+m_i''\tag{2}$.

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have

$$m_i'+m_i''=\inf\{ f(x)+g(y): t_{i-1}\leq x,y \leq t_i \} \leq m_i$$

Comment: With regard to your issue with splitting an inequality in $(1)$, what parts correspond to $\alpha, \beta$, and $\gamma$? $m_i \leq f(x_1)+g(x_1)$ by definition; $m_i'+m_i''\leq f(x)+g(x)$ also by definition; $f(x_1)+g(x_1)<m_i'+m_i''$ is proved using an a proof by contradiction, as I mention right after $(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

[Updated]
WTS:
$$\color{blue}{m_i'+m_i''\leq m_i},$$
where we have defined for another problem:
$$\color{red}{m_i} := \inf\{(f+g)(x)\text{ }|\text{ }x\in [t_{i-1},t_i]\},$$
$$\color{red}{m_i'} := \inf\{f(x)\text{ }|\text{ }x\in [t_{i-1},t_i]\},\text{ and }$$
$$\color{red}{m_i''} := \inf\{g(x)\text{ }|\text{ }x\in [t_{i-1},t_i]\}.$$

---

---

$\underline{\text{Sub-Lemma 1:}}$

$$\color{darkblue}{\forall A,B\in Sets:\text{ }\inf(A)+\inf(B)\leq\inf(A+B)}.$$

$\underline{\text{Sub-Lemma 2:}}$

$$\color{darkblue}{\forall X,Y\in Sets:\text{ }(X\subseteq Y)\implies \big(\inf(Y) \leq \inf(X)\big)}.$$

---

---

$\underline{\text{Proof:}}$

Using *Sub-Lemma 1* in the special case where:
$$\color{red}{A}:= \{f(x)\text{ }|\text{ }x\in [t_{i-1},t_i]\}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\text{ }\color{red}{B}:= \{g(x)\text{ }|\text{ }x\in [t_{i-1},t_i]\},$$
we get the first result:
$$\color{blue}{m_i' + m_i''} = \inf(A)+\inf(B) \color{blue}{\leq} \inf(A+B) = \color{blue}{\inf\{f(x_1)+g(x_2)\text{ }|\text{ }x_1,x_2\in [t_{i-1},t_i]\}}.$$

---

Next, let $x\in [t_{i-1},t_i]$ be given. Then define $\color{red}{x_1} := \color{red}{x_2} := x$. It follows that:
$$(f+g)(x) := f(x)+g(x) = f(x_1)+g(x_2) \in \big\{f(x_1)+g(x_2)\text{ }|\text{ }x_1,x_2\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\big\}.$$
Arbitrariness of $x$ gives:
$$\color{red}{X}:= \big\{(f+g)(x)\text{ }|\text{ }x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\big\} \subseteq \big\{f(x_1)+g(x_2)\text{ }|\text{ }x_1,x_2\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\big\}=:\color{red}{Y}.$$
Applying *Sub-Lemma 2* then yields:
$$\color{blue}{\inf\big\{f(x_1)+g(x_2)\text{ }|\text{ }x_1,x_2\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\big\}} = \inf(Y) \color{blue}{\leq} \inf(X) = \color{blue}{\inf\big\{(f+g)(x)\text{ }|\text{ }x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]\big\}}.$$
Combining the above lighter blue results in sequence proves the result. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you think there is a typo in the problem? Spivak refers to a “first inequality” and a “second inequality”, but there is only a single inequality in the problem statement. Does he perhaps mean proving $$m_i'+m_i''\leq\inf\{f(x_1)+g(x_2):t_{i-1}\leq x_1, x_2\leq t_i\}\leq
 m_i.$$

Comment: Hey! Yes I see the statement has an 'equality' in the first spot, but I don't think you need to prove the reverse direction since the end goal was comparison with $m_i$. The typo in your problem is $y>\in B$. The statement about suprema could have been a decoy to get you to prove the result about the infima? I assume when authors play with the inequalities like that, they are stating both results succinctly or otherwise...

Comment: This seems like a technical result anyways I wouldn't look to deep into it. Instead, I'd ask, why $m_i$, with a free index on an interval? Probably moving towards a statement for integration.